# How to pass record ID to 'Launch Flow in Modal' component in Lightning community

Tags: visual-workflow, lightning-community

I am trying to use the 'Launch Flow in Modal' component in a Lightning Community. I'm placing this button on a Contact record detail page in the Community, and I want to pass the Contact Id to the flow as the input variable 'recordId'.

The options for the component include a field called Flow Input Variables, and the 'info' tooltip for that field gives a syntax example for a JSON string to set the variable that looks like this:

[image]

I can't figure out how to get the record Id of the current contact from the contact detail page inserted into the flow.

First I tried

`[{"name": "recordId", "type": "String", "value": {!Record.Id}}]`

but that throws this error:

`SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 51 of the JSON data`

I figured the brackets around the variable were the problem so I tried escaping them with backslashes:

`[{"name": "recordId", "type": "String", "value": \{!Record.Id\}}]`

but got the same error.

What's the right way to reference the Id of the current record from a community record detail page to pass to a flow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the {!Record.Id} part need to be surrounded by quotation marks?

```
[{"name": "recordId", "type": "String", "value": "{!recordId}"}]
```

Comment: I tried that too, that makes it valid JSON but then it just passes the text string "{!Record.Id}" as the variable, so the flow fails to fetch a record. I'm not sure how to pass the record id as a variable and include it in the JSON with valid syntax.

Comment: Sorry, it needs recordId rather than Record.Id - I've edited the post

Comment: that did it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

On the latest version, the fix can be found at https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A8dhKSAR, which is:

`[{"name" : "recordId", "type" : "String", "value": "_RECORDID_"}]`